# Delete acronym pagenumber in glossary

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I use the following commands to combine and link my acronyms und glossary entries. I wanted this because they are on different pages, the acronyms are displayed before the text and the glossary is displayed after the text, but I wanted to link them so that a reader can jump from acronyms to their glossary entry and the other way round. I use the documentclass article and everything is working fine, except the fact that the first page number which is shown up in the Glossary is always my Acronym Page number. I searched the whole internet already to find a solution to omit the first page number in the glossary or something similar but I didn't find any solution, so maybe someone of you can help me. Attached is a minimal example of what I am meaning, with all the packages I am using in my real project.  [image: Glossary entry with marked page of the acronym]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}                                         % Schriftgröße, Layout, Papierformat, Art des Dokumentes
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includehead]{geometry}      % Einstellungen der Seitenränder
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}                                           % englische, deutsche Silbentrennung
\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}
\usepackage{textcomp} % Text-Companion-Symbols (z. B. \texteuro)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                   % Umlaute
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}                % pfd-Output [Fußnoten nicht verlinken]
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}                                                % Inhaltsverzeichniserweiterung (Inhaltsverzeichnis selbst ausblenden)
\usepackage{makeidx}                                                          % Index
%\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}                                                   % altes Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                                         % Fancy Header
\usepackage{pdfpages}                                                         % For PDF include in the Appendix
\usepackage[round]{natbib}                                                    % Zitate (Erweiterung für Literaturverzeichnis)
\usepackage{amsmath}                                                          % Zurücksetzen der Tabellen- und Abbildungsnummerierung je Sektion
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,aboveskip=1mm]{caption}                              % Bild- und Tabellenunterschrift (fett) 
\usepackage{setspace}                                                         % Zeilenabstand (vor footmisc laden!)
\usepackage[bottom,multiple,hang,marginal]{footmisc}                          % Fußnoten [Ausrichtung unten, Trennung durch Seperator bei mehreren Fußnoten]
\usepackage{wrapfig}                                                          % Umfließende Grafiken und Tabellen
\usepackage{graphicx}                                                         % Grafiken
\usepackage{tabularx}                                                         % erweiterte Tabellen
\usepackage{longtable}                                                        % mehrseitige Tabellen
\usepackage{color}                                                            % Farben
\usepackage{enumitem}                                                         % Befehl setlist (Zeilenabstand für itemize Umgebung auf 1 setzen)
\usepackage{listings}                                                         % Quelltexte
\usepackage{zref}                                                             % Verweise (Anhangsverweise)
\usepackage[toc,translate=false,acronym]{glossaries}                    % Glossar (nach hyperref, inputenc, babel und ngerman)
\usepackage{glossaries-babel}                                                 % Glossar: Übersetzung im TOC
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xspace}
\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300
\usepackage{multicol}
\parindent0mm

%%%%%%%%% Zusatz %%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}                                                       % Blockkommentar ermöglichen
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[figure,table,lstlisting]{totalcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}% provides dummy text for testing
\usepackage{microtype} 


%Ein eigenes Symbolverzeichnis erstellen
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis}

%Den Punkt am Ende jeder Beschreibung deaktivieren
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}

%Glossar-Befehle anschalten
\makeglossaries

%%% Definition Glossary entry

\newglossaryentry{APIG}{name=\glslink{API}{Application Programming Interface (\gls{API})},description={An Application Programming Interface is a particular set
of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software program that implements that API.}}

%%% Definition Acronym

\newglossaryentry{API}{ 
type=\acronymtype,
name={API},
first=\glslink{APIG}{Application Programming Interface (API)},
firstplural={Application Programming Interfaces (API's)},
description=\glslink{APIG}{Application Programming Interfaces \emph{(siehe Glossar)}}
}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\newpage

%Neuen Style erstellen
%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter 
\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
   \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{description}% 
    \setlength{\itemindent}{-2.5em}
     }{\end{description}}% 
   \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
   \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
   \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\indexspace}%
} 
\newglossarystyle{mylistdotted}{
   \glossarystyle{mylist}
   \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{
     \item[]\makebox[\glslistdottedwidth][l]{\glstarget{##1}{##2}
     \unskip\leaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill\strut}##3}
   \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{
     \item[]\makebox[\glslistdottedwidth][l]{\glstarget{##2}{##3}
     \unskip\leaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill\strut}##4}
} 
\makeatother  
%%%%%%%%%

%Abkürzungen ausgeben
\deftranslation[to=German]{Acronyms}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\setglossarystyle{mylistdotted}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis] 
\newpage

\section{Allgemeines}
use the Glossary \gls{API}
\\
this should be the first pagenumber in the glossary
\newpage

%Glossar ausgeben
\printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossar]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a full compilable document demonstarting this.  It means we can test solutions much more easily, and it's always possible that package options (which you haven't shown) are relevant.

Comment: So no one can help me? :(

Comment: with the code you provide I can't replicate the problem.  Exactly what steps do you follow (applied to the code above) to get the problematic output?  It doesn't appear to generate the acronyms page at all.

Comment: I am using ShareLatex because I work from different PC with no options at all just compile and Acronym and Glossar is there as I described