# Remove first link from list of abbreviations

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I have a glossary formatted as given in the answer of @mafp 
which works perfectly for my purposes.

However adding this solution in my main tex file which is a thesis, in the page where the list is printed i always get a link for the appearance in the list. Is there any way to remove this first entry?

The same problem appeared in the related [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356655/delete-acronym-pagenumber-in-glossary) of @Max, but there is no solution.

The working example @mafp gave is

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        filecolor=magenta,      
        urlcolor=cyan,
    }

    \usepackage{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries

    \renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{} % not to show word glossary


    \newglossaryentry{A}{%
    name={foo},%
    description={bar},%
    %user1={cm}%
    }

    \newglossaryentry{B}{%
    name={AAPL},%
    description={apples},%
    %user1={box}%
    }

    \newglossaryentry{C}{%
    name={BTR},%
    description={books to read},%
    %user1={LoC}%
    }

    \newglossaryentry{D}{%
    name={BTRTIO},%
    description={books to read that I own},%
    %user1={shelf},%
    %parent={C}
    }

    \newglossarystyle{aiaostyle}{%
    % put the glossary in a longtable environment:
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}{lp{\glsdescwidth}cp{\glspagelistwidth}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
    % Set the table’s header: title row
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
     \bfseries Term & \bfseries Description & 
     \bfseries Units & \bfseries Page List
     \\\endhead}%
    % No table header:
    %\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    % No heading between groups:
     \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    % Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row optionally numbered:
     \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{##2}% Name
        & ##3% Description
        & \glsentryuseri{##1}% Units
        & ##5% Page list
        \\% end of row
     }%
    % Similarly for sub-entries (no sub-entry numbers):
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
        % ignoring first argument (sub-level)
        \glstarget{##2}{##3}% Name
        & ##4% Description
        & \glsentryuseri{##2}% Units
        & ##6% Page list
        \\% end of row
     }%
    % Nothing between groups:
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
    }



    \begin{document}
    \null
    \glsaddall

    \glossarystyle{aiaostyle}
    \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
    \setlength{\glspagelistwidth}{0.1\textwidth}
    \printglossaries

    \newpage
    test entry \gls{A}.

    \end{document}
```

I am sorry for writting a new question but i cannot comment below the solution of @mapf since this is my first appearance in `TeX.SE`.

Comment: I can't compile the example since it fails due to some error in the definition of `aiaostyle`, but perhaps `\glsdisablehyper` is useful; at the moment `hyperref` is not loaded anyway ;-) Side note:  `\glossarystyle` is a deprecated command, use `\setglossarystyle` instead, please.... and welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: Are you referring to the first number in the location list for each entry, which in your MWE is created with `\glsaddall` at the start of your document?

Comment: I have changed the MWE to show the effect of hyperref in many pages. But @NicolaTalbot had already answered. Can you please post this as an answer so that i can accept it? You 've been very helpful.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks for the notification for the deprecated command. Although it seems that in the particular example it produces an error. I 'll play around with it and maybe i will figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\glsadd{`*label*`}` is an indexing command that automatically adds a location to the entry's number list. `\glsaddall` iterates over all the defined entries and uses `\glsadd` for each entry. It's designed for use in conjunction with the `nonumberlist` option to automatically include all entries in the glossary, regardless of whether or not you have used them in the document (with commands like `\gls`). If the number list isn't suppressed, `\glsaddall` will cause all entries to have an extra location corresponding to the place in the document where `\glsaddall` was used.

If you want a number list and you want to include all defined entries, regardless of whether or not they have been used in the document, then you can put `\glsaddallunused` *at the end of the document* to add any remaining entries that haven't been used.